# Alpha Sorting JSON API with nested values in php

Tags: php, api, sorting

I have a php function that pulls some json API. I'm using it to produce a list, the list is not currently alpha sorted.

```
$json   = file_get_contents('URL');
$obj    = json_decode($json);
$array  = array($obj);
foreach($array[0] as $i => $sector){
    foreach ($sector as $obj) {
        echo $obj->Names[0]->Text;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of the JSON I'm getting.

```
{"Sectors":
    [
    {"X":0,"Y":-21,
     "Names":[
        {
         "Text":"BoB",
         "Lang":"xx"
        }
     ]
    },
    {"X":3,"Y":-31,
     "Names":[
        {
         "Text":"SAL",
         "Lang":"yy"
        }
     ]
    },
    ]
}
```

How do I alpha sort by "Names"?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the original input data, please?

Comment: Do you just want to isolate that one "Names" node and sort that it's Text value?

Comment: Data example is the JSON provided.  I currently turn this JSON into an array..but would like to alpha sort the results by the "Names" field..  Most sorting functions seem to have issue with objects containing arrays and then sorting those arrays properly...

Comment: Yes just sorting the "Names" node, After even more thought on this. I think the best way to go is to read the Names ->Text and just build a new (and flat) array..THEN alpha sort that new array..essentially stripping down the JSON to something more managable... instead of working with this wonky JSON layout.